# Using setformulas to copy both values and formulas down a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

PROBLEM:  In the below spreadsheet, cells C12:C17 (green) contain text imported from another spreadsheet (The "PARENT").
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1brm0dHkXG1vxn2NQ7wGvEoayCdGYKsY4yA-MX4Jtt1w/edit#gid=396314711

Some cells have text.  Some are blank.  Some contain simple math (i.e 1+1), and others relational math (i.e. A1+B1).  The DATA SET in the PARENT sheet are different than the CHILD sheet.  I will eventually have to create a lot of CHILD sheets, each with their own unique DATA SET.  The formulas on the PARENT sheet will change from time to time, so the solution isn't to just make a copy of the PARENT spreadsheet and turn it into a CHILD sheet.

I need to be able to create the formulas in the PARENT sheet, but when imported into the CHILD sheet, they need to be calculated using the data set on the CHILD sheet.

I'm trying to use a script that will take what is in the C12:C17 range, and make it an active formula in the corresponding D12:D17 cells.  If the C column cell is a value, it should just put that value in there instead of making it into a formula.

I've made about a dozen attempts at the setFormulas script.  All failed.  At this point, I would say I'm "spit-balling", "flailing", and possibly "spiraling".  The BEST I've been able to do is to get ONE cell to update (but only if a formula, not text).

I'm looking for a script that will take whatever is in cells C12:C17, and execute/evaluate them into cells D12:D17.  If there are text/values in the C cell, then it should put that text/value in the corresponding D cell.  If there is a formula in the C cell, it should make it execute in the corresponding D cell.  There is no pattern on whether a cell will be a number, text, or formula.

I appreciate any help you can give.

FYI: The formulas/text in the C column were made by importing from the PARENT sheet.  That range of cells in the PARENT sheet was made by the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(FORMULATEXT('P CUSTOMERS'!B12),'P CUSTOMERS'!B12)
```

Essentially, "If it's a formula, convert it into text.  If it's not a formula , just put what is in the cell in the first place ."

I've been working on this for an embarrassing amount of time...  (Not hours, not days, not weeks, but MONTHS!).

EDIT / UPDATE:
OK, Marti's scripts worked great in the example file.  Moved it to another file, same conditions, and worked again.

THEN, I moved it to another file...  Only difference I can tell is that it is MUCH larger.

EDIT SUMMARY:
Ran the script under these conditions.

Made table with formulas.  Used FORMULATEXT on that table to convert into text.  Imported that range to another sheet.  Used an HLOOKUP formula to select which column I wanted to look at formulas for.

In the sample sheet (linked here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cPSJMXNiKDnHCiUCGJ0iSjaoIiRLQldr1T5rClUUEm0/copy), it works.

But when I run the exact same series of events in another sheet, it fails to do anything.  Process is the same, only the range is different.  No other scripts on this sheet.

I trimmed down the second sheet so I can share (script still doesn't work).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RRMy4RtF9CVSXw18bWg79Dh4nwHg8IN3wwhLb3QynvA/edit#gid=236899042

(Note: I can't force a copy, as this sheet requires authorizations from another file)

Here is a video better explaining the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pjz_LilRReQlNt7p_4NhU3prtbcAhLah/view?usp=sharing

So, I'm trying to understand why it works in one, but not the other...  And just as important, what can I do to make it work in 2nd sheet, which is actual goal.

Comment: can you make the CHILD editable (rather than View Only) so we can attempt a solution there?

Comment: MattKing.  I made the change.  Sorry about that...  Editable now.

Comment: In general I favor making a copy. If you try something that doesn't work people down the line have to deal with your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `getValues` together with `setValues`. `setValues` actually interprets values starting with `=` as formulas, and `getValues` actually doesn't add the `'` before them. So you can simply chain them:

```js
function computeValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const s = ss.getSheets()[0]

  const src = s.getRange('C12:C')
  const target = src.offset(0, 1)

  target.setValues(src.getValues())
}
```

### References

- [Range.getValues() (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Range.setValues(values) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Range.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)

Comment: You have saved my sanity and restored my faith in humanity!  I don't have enough reputation on this website to upvote your response, but if I could, I would a thousand times!  Thank you!

Comment: OK, I've used this formula, and it seems to sometimes work, sometimes no...  I will post a video and further description below.  Would appreciate your further advice

Comment: @RogueScientistAllen instead of posting the answer again, the Stack Overflow way of mark that this answer solver your question is by [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/899642) :)

Comment: Thank you!  I understand, but I updated the question with the edit.  It seems that the solution doesn't always work.  I provided additional videos and spreadsheets demonstrating the variation.

Comment: @RogueScientistAllen From the edit you made, you seem to be selecting the wrong sheet. In my code I select the first one. Change `ss.getSheets()[0]` with `ss.getSheetByName('Targeted sheet name here' )` to get a sheet by name.

Comment: Again, you are a genius!!!  I am downgrading myself from "Spreadsheet Amateur" to merely a "Spreadsheet Enthusiast"!

Answer (score 0):

Martí nailed it...

```
function computeValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const s = ss.getSheets()[0]

  const src = s.getRange('C12:C')
  const target = src.offset(0, 1)

  target.setValues(src.getValues())
}
```

I tested it, as written, by copy/paste.  Worked 1st time.

I added in more formulas below the original range, just to see what the limits were (in cell C20), and re-ran it.  Still worked.

I would have kept going in my setFormula direction for another few months.  Not sure how I got it stuck in my head that was the only solution.  This was the final major barrier in my project, and while I still have another few years of manual data entry and formula creation to do, THIS will be the key that makes it all work.  THANK YOU!!!